# Llamar función instanciada en el controlador - Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo un controlador en el cual estoy incluyendo un archivo ubicado en la carpeta public. Dicho archivo contiene una clase y dentro de la clase sus respectivas funciones; en el store del controlador estoy realizando lo siguiente

```
include public_path().'/nombreArchivo.php';

public function store(Request $request)
{
  if($request['tipo'] == 'campotrue')
  {
     $cliente = new Paquete();
     $cliente->Adicionar($id, $request['nombre'], $request['icono']);
  }
}
```

Y el archivo ubicado en la carpeta public tiene esto otro

```
class Paquete
{

  function Adicionar($id, $nombre, $icono)
  {
     #operación de la función
  }
}
```

A lo que consigo el error `BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2123: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::Adicionar()`.
¿A qué se debe este error y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: ¿cómo estás incluyendo la clase externa? Podemos ver algo de ese archivo?

Comment: Revisa la edición por favor

Comment: Prueba llamar el include dentro de la función store. `public function store(Request $request)
{
 include(public_path() . '/nombreArchivo.php');
 $cliente = new Paquete();
         $cliente->Adicionar($id, $request['nombre'], $request['icono']); ...`

Answer (score 3):

Revisando tu pregunta lo primero que veo es un problema de seguridad. No debes agregar nunca tu código php en la carpeta `public`, esa carpeta será accesada por los usuarios sin restricciones.

Lo correcto es guardarlo en la carpeta `App\`. Ahí puedes crear una carpeta y guardar tu archivo por ejemplo en la dirección `App\Classes\nombreArchivo.php`

Una vez guardado el archivo en la ubicación correcta, debe asignarse el namespace que tendrá. El código debería ser algo así:

```
<?php

namespace App\Classes;

class Paquete
{
  function Adicionar($id, $nombre, $icono)
  {
     #operación de la función
  }
}
```

Con lo anterior ya tendríamos la clase correctamente creada ahora sólo falta utilizarla. Para esto en el controlador indicas que vas a usar la nueva clase. El código sería algo así:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Classes\Paquete;

class PagesController extends Controller
{

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
      if($request['tipo'] == 'campotrue')
      {
         $cliente = new Paquete();
         $cliente->Adicionar($id, $request['nombre'], $request['icono']);
      }
    } 
}
```